# google-fusion-table add column to view

Tags: google-fusion-tables

My situation is this: 
I have one master fusion table with all data about all clients (with permissions only to me). 
I created another table that will have limited info (with permission to my team)

I decided I need to collect another piece of information. I CAN add a column to the master table, but I can't find a way to now select the column for the limited views. The only option I can see is delete the very elaborate limited view, and re-do it from the beginning.

There has to be a better way! What am I missing?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think at the moment this can not be done, because it's not possible to change the definition of a view after it has been created. This would be a nice feature, though. You can [request it on the project site](http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/) ;)

All you can do now is create a new view. What exactly is "elaborate" about the current view? It shouldn't be too hard to "migrate" to a new one.

Comment: I have multiple tabs of views and charts and summaries, as well as a very specific way to filter each, and also a specific arrangement for the columns. Send me your email and I'll be happy to share my data with you and show you the design. If you have an idea of how I can easily migrate all the settings when creating a view again (without having to go through it all manually..) that would be amazing!

Comment: Okay, I see. In this case it's not as easy as I thought. Now there is only one way I can think of: If you could put the data of the new column in a seperate table, you could merge this new table into the current view and keep all your settings.